# Changing server IP after connecting to CloudFlare

Tags: cloudflare

I recently signed up for CloudFlare to take advantage of the security feautres the service provides. Specifically, I'm interested in its use against DDOS attacks (which are a problem I'm facing).

My web application employs nginx as a **reverse proxy** (with gunicorn as the application server). The Ubuntu-based virtual machine - procured via Azure - has a static/reserved IP (used as a VIP). I've read that after connecting to CloudFlare, it's best practice to change server IP so that malicious actors can't directly DDOS the said server.

Being a newbie, I'm unsure whether this guideline was applicable to the public VIP (virtual IP) or to the internal IP (which is entirely different). Can someone please conceptually and functionally clarify this for me? Can really use some help in setting this up!

Comment: Since your public IP has leaked already you need a new one and should not leave any footprint of it i.e. via MX records.

Comment: @Xaqron: I haven' set up email (i.e. no MX records). But can't the IP just be gotten via pinging my domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What services like [`CloudFlare`](https://www.cloudflare.com/) do is acting like a [`CDN`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) for your website. They become front-end of your content delivery to clients while they have vast network for doing so (resources i.e. bandwidth which are consumed by `DDoS`). Then your `IP` is just known by the anti-DDoS service provider to fetch the content and deliver on your behalf.

You see if the `IP` is leaked by any mean the whole defense mechanism become useless since attackers can directly point to your machine while [dynamic DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) of [`CloudFlare`](https://www.cloudflare.com/) would distribute requests to its network and serve clients via them.

Since your website was up for a while before you migrate to `CloudFlare` your current public `IP` is known to attackers and hiding behind [`CloudFlare`](https://www.cloudflare.com/) is useless since they don't ask [`CloudFlare`](https://www.cloudflare.com/) `DNS` service and directly attack your server. This is the reason you need a new `IP` and the new one should not be revealed by any mean. Just set it in your [`CloudFlare`](https://www.cloudflare.com/) panel and don't use it for other purposes.

Comment: can you message me directly at ryank[at]cloudflare or DM me via Twitter at @yank? have a question for you

Answer (score 0):

I faced attacks too and used CloudFlare to prevent them, however, I have learned how to perform those attacks by myself and also how to bypass CloudFlare and take down the protected website. The best practice is to secure your server by yourself. Using nginx as a reverse proxy is a good option.

Comment: What other measures did you take, apart from using nginx as a reverse proxy (which I'm already doing)?